# Enviar foto e json no mesmo request - Postman

Tags: php, json, rest, slim, postman

Estou com problemas para enviar na mesma requisição uma foto e um json pelo postman.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso enviar a foto de perfil do usuário e ao mesmo tempo receber um json com os dados do mesmo.

```
 //Instância da entidade Login
        $login = new Login();
        //recuperando o parâmetro objeto login do json
        $fk_login_cidadao = $request->getParam('fk_login_cidadao');
        //setando valores do objeto login
        $login ->setLogin($fk_login_cidadao['login']);
        $login ->setEmail($fk_login_cidadao['email']);
        $login ->setSenha($fk_login_cidadao['senha']);
        $login ->setStatus_login($fk_login_cidadao['status_login']);
        $login ->setAsAdministrador($fk_login_cidadao['administrador']);
        //salvando login
        $entityManager->persist($login);
        $entityManager->flush();
        //buscando login recém salvo
        $loginRepository = $entityManager->getRepository('App\Models\Entity\Login');
        //pegando login
        $loginCidadao = $loginRepository->find($login->getId_login());


        //Salvar foto
        $files = $request->getUploadedFiles();
        $newimage = $files['foto'];

        if ($newimage->getError() === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $uploadFileName = $newimage->getClientFilename();
            $type = $newimage->getClientMediaType();
            $name = uniqid('img-' . date('d-m-y') . '-');
            $name .= $newimage->getClientFilename();
            //  $imgs[] = array('url' => '/Photos/' . $name);

            //local server

            $newimage->moveTo("C:\Users\jvict\PhpstormProjects\api.webservice\img");#/home/citycare/Imgs/User/$name

            //localdev
            $photoURL = "C:\Users\jvict\PhpstormProjects\api.webservice\img";#/home/citycare/Imgs/User/$name

        }

        //Instância da entidade Cidadao
        $cidadao = new Cidadao();
        //setando valores do objeto cidadao
        $cidadao ->setFk_login_cidadao($loginCidadao);
        $cidadao->setNome($request->getParam('nome'));
        $cidadao->setSexo($request->getParam('sexo'));
        $cidadao ->setSobrenome($request->getParam('sobrenome'));
        $cidadao ->setEstado($request->getParam('estado'));
        $cidadao ->setCidade($request->getParam('cidade'));
        $cidadao ->setDir_foto_usuario($request->getParam($photoURL));
        $entityManager->persist($cidadao);
        $entityManager->flush();
        //retornando confirmação do evento completo
        $return = $response->withJson(["result" => true],201)->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
```

Comment: Você já tentou mudar o content-type pra **multipart/form-data**? Outra solução seria enviar a imagem codificada em base64 dentro do JSON com as informações e no PHP decodificar o base64 e gerar o arquivo.

Comment: com o content-type assim n funciona, eu tô recebendo a img de um app android, então no caso p codificar p base64 seria no app ?

Comment: Sim, é possível codificar para base64 em Java no Android.

Comment: Obrigado amigo!

Comment: Deu certo a solução?